# Custom Membership Provider - Error in my custom CreateUser Function with different parameters

Tags: .net, asp.net, custom-membershipprovider

I want to Create a new User using Custom Membership Provider but I don't want to use the default function that is created.

I don't want to use this

```
Public Overrides Function CreateUser(ByVal username As String,
                                         ByVal password As String,
                                         ByVal email As String,
                                         ByVal passwordQuestion As String,
                                         ByVal passwordAnswer As String,
                                         ByVal isApproved As Boolean,
                                         ByVal providerUserKey As Object,
                                         ByRef status As System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateStatus) As System.Web.Security.MembershipUser
        Return Nothing
  End Function
```

Instead I want to use this

```
Public Overloads Function CreateUser(ByVal username As String,
                                         ByVal email As String,
                                         ByVal number As String,
                                         ByVal isApproved As Boolean,
                                          ByRef status As System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateStatus) As System.Web.Security.MembershipUser
```

So when I use second option I get this squiggly lines saying "**Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference**"

I referenced the .dll correctly like this

```
Imports CustomProviders
```

But when I try to create a user as shown in this below image it doesn't work.  I am doing something clearly wrong.  I don't know what it is.

[image]

**Resolved**:
I found that the squiggly line was due to casting problem.  I was referencing the class library member without casting in my web page code behind method.  I think the other is also taken care off.

Comment: Could you post your code of second method? Or atleast those lines where you get Squiggly lines? I suspect you are using some memeber which is not shared. IN such cases, you would have to use the member like ObjectName.Member name.. so post your code and we'll find out

Comment: There is the squiggly line in the picture at the bottom where it says, "CreateUser".  And I will update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey, your code works (compiles okay with me) I just created a new membership provider and used your createuser method. It works Okay.

If you just want to send less parameters, why dont you use optional parameter feature so that your caller's can still call the method with limited parameters. This way you will automatically get out of your problem (which I am not sure what is :) ?)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f25e2b6b(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Actually my code was working but the squiggly lines was due to not casting the type membership into my page behind class.  So I had to use DirectCast(Membership.Provider, MembershipProvider).CreateUser()  which is working. Thanks for your help